# Applying pixelwise operations are slow

Tags: java, android, opencv

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    Mat rgb=inputFrame.rgba();
    for(int y=0;y<rgb.cols();++y){
        for(int x=0;x<rgb.rows();++x){
            double[]pixelValues=rgb.get(x,y);
            double redVal=pixelValues[0];
            double greenVal=pixelValues[1];
            double blueVal=pixelValues[2];
            double alphaVal=pixelValues[3];
            double gryVal=(redVal+greenVal+blueVal)/3;
            rgb.put(x,y,gryVal,gryVal,gryVal,alphaVal);
        }
    }
    return rgb;
}
```

This is my code to change the pixel values of a cameraStream displayed inside a JavaCameraView component. The thing is this is very  slow. less than 3 fps. I know there is a faster way to get gray scale images `{.rgba() => .gray()` or using `Improc.cvt()}`. Though i need the freedom to handle pixels by my self. my ultimate goal is to get something which i can adjust red, green, blue colors as i like.

Is there is a way to make this atleast get 30fps (smooth framerates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get and put operations for every pixel will surely results in poor fps because of overhead of native calls.Instead ,you  should call get and put operations only once.i.e outside the for loop.Single call to get/put them into java primitive arrays and do operations on them.This way you can do your own pixel operations and it will boost performance greatly(more closer to imgproc.cvt()). 
http://answers.opencv.org/question/5/how-to-get-and-modify-the-pixel-of-mat-in-java/
This will show you an example of how to make single get/put calls(Not only the actual answer but also see in comments).

Comment: It's working now. Next thing is about the byte[]. So lets Think I need to remove all the red values and replace with green Values. How can i implement the for Loop.. Is that can be done like this???? for(int i =0;i<array.length;i+=3){array[i]=array[i+1];} This Has done assuming the array is arranged like {redVal,greenVAl,blueVal,redVal,.......} Is this true? Or is there someother way?????

Comment: you will get values in BGR format.i.e {B,G,R,B,G,R...so on}.your for loop must skip blue channel to swap R and G channels.Think about logic.I can give you that one but you might be pleased if you can do yourself.And careful in using byte array.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412000/opencv-java-grayscale/38413469#38413469. see this link

Comment: Can I know what should I do to capture frames from JavaCameraView to save it as a video.. I refered the opencv documents but didn't found any answers.. I need to capture the manipulated frames.

Comment: Is The byte[]={B,G,R,B,G,R} or {R,G,B,A,R,G,B,A} class was implementing cvviewliasterener2 interface

Comment: I do not know video recording which I never attempt to do. Opencv color format is BGR if alpha present it should be BGRA.This is general case when an image is loaded from storage using imread.As your case is live feed data it could RGB or RGBA based on java interface.So save the frame using imwrite to know pixel format RGB or BGR.

Comment: And from this statement  Mat rgb=inputFrame.rgba(); I assume it could be RGBA.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I will look more into the recording thing.